# IP white address not accepting my current IP

Tags: users

It says "*Enter the list of allowed IP addresses below*

> Warning: If you don't enter your current IP address into the list, you will immediately be locked out of the system upon save, and will not be able to access the system until you are in a location with an allowed IP address."

So I am trying to white list all Australian IP and ban all other with this simple module called [Restrict IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_ip) but when I go to input my current IP which by the way is dynamic so I don't see how that will help if it keeps changing. Anyway I found a list of IP in Australia from **[here](https://kb.cadzow.com.au:444/cadzow/details.aspx?ID=2088)** and have input them all but when I got to save configuration it says is not a valid IP address.

Actually does this module only blacklist IP trying to login the site or does it blacklist viewing as well? I only want to blacklist login and register all IP outside of Australia.

Comment: why have I been marked down here? answers have been marked up- the inconsistency between the two ratings is illogical.

Comment: no doubt by ageist misogynistic trolls- ha

Comment: Don't worry too much about 'anonymous' downvotes ... because downvoting questions is "cheap" (it does not cost the downvoter a -1 rep decrease, like it does for downvoting answers). Some day somebody will come along and issue an upvote ... which compensates for 2,5 downvotes ... because 2,5*(-2) + 5 = 0, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Restrict IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/restrict_ip) module clearly states:

> This module allows administrators to restrict access to the site to an administrator defined set of IP addresses. **Anyone trying to access the site from an IP address not in the list of allowed IP addresses will be redirected to an access denied page** with the message "Your address is not in the list of allowed IP addresses".

Emphasis mine. So it restricts access to the *site*, not the login form.

If you're adding a valid IP address, and the module is saying it's not a valid IP, you've found a bug and need to report it to the issue queue on Drupal.org.

If you're serious about restricting people by geographic region you'll need to come up with something better than IP address, which is not reliable for such things.

Comment: well the weird thing is it is now telling me what my current IP is and at the same time rejecting it.

Comment: really? then I may as well delete it.

Comment: however i am not convinced it is a bug as you say.

Comment: Clive, please take a look at my deleted answer. Maybe I should undelete it? I got confused what this question is about, now I'm starting to think my answer might be relevant.

Comment: What happens if your IP keeps on changing ?

Comment: @Mołot Yeah you're probably right. .0 and .255 are not 'valid' IPs in this sense as they're reserved for network and broadcast respectively

Comment: @cea What do you mean? What happens to what?

Comment: if my ip changes everytime my adsl reconnects , wouldn't be locked out next time that happens because my subsequent IP wouldn't be added?

Comment: Correct @cea. That's how string matching works. I think you're expecting Drupal to be able to solve a situation that it couldn't possibly.

Comment: hmmm I am trying to find a way to disclude people from out of Australia or at least identify who they are.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. What's to stop them just connecting through a proxy?

Comment: That said, you may be able to make some use of [IP2Country](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip2country)

Comment: well i might have to do it old fashioned way and just speak to ppl individually and get them to prove it by going in my stats page!

Comment: Sometimes the old ways are the best @cea ;)

Comment: yep this is true!  :)

Answer (score 2):

You could give a try to [IP Ranges Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_ranges) which is actively maintained

> Type can be either "blacklist" or "whitelist", where blacklisted IP's
> are denied from the site, and whitelisted are allowed.
>
> Whitelists always override blacklists.

- Restrict IP allows you to enter whitelists. All other IP's are banned.
  Unlike IP Ranges, it does not actually restrict access to the page, but rather
  unsets all the regions.
- It also may serve pages even to banned IP:s if the requested page can be retrieved from cache.

Comment: interesting..."unsets all the regions" what do you mean?

Comment: COUNTRY BAN looks closest to what I'd want but none for 7.

Answer (score 2):

Site you linked provides ranges with last byte `.0` and `.255` at their ends. Generally, `.255` is reserved for broadcasts, and `.0` for network ID, so modules may rightly not consider it a valid IP addresses.

This may lead to all kinds of unexpected behaviour, especially when the module you are using is still in unstable version. Release Candidates should be pretty stable, but they can be expected to have some minor issues still unsolved, especially with data that shouldn't be entered in the first place.